# How to forward the Internet through the OPENVPN client?

Tags: linux, openvpn, firewalld

There is an Openvpn server and two clients
How will all traffic for client 1 be routed through client 2?

Server

```
tun0 10.8.0.1
```

client 1

```
tun0 10.8.0.2
```

client 2

```
tun0 10.8.0.3
```

я хочу чтобы весь интернет проходил через клиента 2
в настройках ccd для клиента 1 пишу

```
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.8.0.3"
```

On client 2 in tcpdump -i tun0 nothing

Comment: If the diagram is correct then you probably don't need another OpenVPN configuration, but just some routing entries and firewall rules

Comment: Relevant IP addresses, subnet masks, and routing tables would help tremendously

Comment: Please add information to your question. Updates here in the comments can all to easily get missed. (And comments get deleted.)

Comment: Thank you. (1) Your "_Server configuration_" - that's for VPS 1, used for the clients that connect? (2) Are the clients out on the Internet, or are they internal as shown in the diagram?

Comment: Please add information to your question. Updates here in the comments can all to easily get missed. (And comments can get deleted.)

Comment: Are there any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.